# need an example trying to use svg/png

Tags: java, android, xml, svg, gridview

This is my first post...im a beginner trying to make an app for android. 
im trying to make a simple match game using a deck of playing cards. Ive been able to get open source svg and png playing cards online. They either come in individual cards images (in png or svg formats) or one image (svg or png) with every card spaced nicely with a contrast background.
With all of the research ive done, i try to utilize these svg or png files but run into either out of memory issues or very slow UX performance.

My goal is to get a gridview to show all 52 cards that swipe horizontally. and if i click on a card, and match its face...then i get a point.

heres my layout activty_play_board.xml
just have one item...a gridview:

```
  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="540dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
```

I use this public class that i got from googles dev website. it allows me to fill in the gridview with the svg or png cards

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 270));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setPadding(4,4, 4, 4);
       } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.two_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.two_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.two_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.two_of_spades,
        R.drawable.three_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.three_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.three_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.three_of_spades,
        R.drawable.four_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.four_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.four_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.four_of_spades,
        R.drawable.five_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.five_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.five_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.five_of_spades,
        R.drawable.six_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.six_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.six_of_spades,
        R.drawable.six_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.seven_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.seven_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.seven_of_spades,
        R.drawable.seven_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.eight_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.eight_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.eight_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.eight_of_spades,
        R.drawable.nine_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.nine_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.nine_of_spades,
        R.drawable.nine_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.ten_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.ten_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.ten_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.ten_of_spades,
        R.drawable.jack_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.jack_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.jack_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.jack_of_spades,
        R.drawable.queen_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.queen_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.queen_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.queen_of_spades,
        R.drawable.king_of_spades,
        R.drawable.king_of_clubs,
        R.drawable.king_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.king_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.ace_of_spades,
        R.drawable.ace_of_diamonds,
        R.drawable.ace_of_hearts,
        R.drawable.ace_of_clubs
};}
```

heres my onCreate:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_board);
    Button goBackOnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBoardButton);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(newAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(GridBoard.this, "Spot: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
});
```

I have several questions.

1. How do i utilize the SVG file? am i calling the one big svg file and then referencing a specific location on the file when i call it for an imageview within my gridview?
2. i dont know how to use the one big SVG file, so ive tried using the individual svg images. but when i do that, my device is very laggy and slow. also sometimes the app crashes due to out of memory errors. Is there a special syntax to use when trying to reference a specific card within the large SVG file? Or do i have to manually edit the big svg file and get the smaller cards?
3. Is there a better way to do this than using a gridview?
4. any other general guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Heres my card sources:
one big palette
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/English_pattern_playing_cards_deck.svg
individual cards and one big palette
http://byronknoll.blogspot.com/2011/03/vector-playing-cards.html

Comment: could anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: See this [Android: how to draw .svg file's elements separetly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469319/android-how-to-draw-svg-files-elements-separetly/50526920#50526920)