# Android: how to draw .svg file's elements separetly?

Tags: java, android, svg, canvas

I have `.svg` a file with some elements in it. Is there any way to draw them step by step on the canvas?

I'm using `com.caverock:androidsvg` library, but it seems like there is no way to extract individual element.

Comment: just create different .svg files and put in each one one of your elements.

Comment: @user3816569 It's not really efficient to create hundreds of files)

Comment: hmm, in that case check the answer from Paul LeBeau from these two threads maybe it helps : [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959050/how-to-define-click-event-separately-for-each-path-element) [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713383/a-svg-image-have-6-icon-and-need-to-choose-one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my test example video. I copied one `Path` from 250 (the white outline in the middle of the image, that does not pan or scroll). It was the first `Path` in the `SVG` document, and the *first element* in the `List` of `Path'`s
[image]

> "I have `.svg` file with some elements in it. Is there any way to draw
>   them step by step on the canvas?"

Yes you can do this (at least for the important [Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) data), see [Android path tracing](http://www.curious-creature.com/2013/12/21/android-recipe-4-path-tracing/) tutorial, and the source code in the `github` [here](https://github.com/romainguy/road-trip). The demo (`road-trip`) extracts (actually it *`intercepts`*) the [Path's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path)  and also animates these 
[`android.graphics.Path's`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) (with `android.animation.ObjectAnimator`). [You Tube](https://youtu.be/-NxG3BE9QCg).

> The library I picked, `androidsvg`, is easy to use but does not give
>   access to the paths contained in the `SVG` document. I worked around
>   this issue by creating a custom Canvas that intercepts `drawPath()`
>   calls:

```
//list of Path's
private final List<VecPath> mPaths = new ArrayList<VecPath>();

Canvas canvas = new Canvas() {
    private final Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

    @Override
    public void drawPath(Path path, Paint paint) {
        Path dst = new Path();

        // Get the current transform matrix
        getMatrix(mMatrix);
        // Apply the matrix to the path
        path.transform(mMatrix, dst);
        // Store the transformed path
        mPaths.add(new SvgPath(dst, new Paint(mSourcePaint)));
    }
};

// Load an SVG document
SVG svg = SVG.getFromResource(context, R.raw.map_usa);
// Capture the paths
svg.renderToCanvas(canvas);
```

## Note

Remember the [`.SVG`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) format is a *document* file, *not* just a simple  vector image type. 
You *possibly* could *modify* the [`viewBox`](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) to select different images from your `.SVG` document, using the code above.

```
<svg
   width="650"
   height="1000"
   viewBox="40 350 900 1050"
   id="svg1">
```